# How to move a single vector on Riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

On Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, we know
$$
u^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}v^{\nu}=0
$$
determinates the curve on which we can move $v^{\nu}$ parallel. But here $v^{\nu}$ is a vector field. If we are in Euclidean space, we can move a single vector freely, so my question is how to define the movement of a single vector on a curve in Riemannian manifold?

I think because I only have a single vector on one point, I can't use the covariant derivative. But Lie derivative is still helpful because it only depends on the map between two manifolds. But I don't know whether we can read a map between two manifolds from a curve on manifold.

I would be very grateful for any hints or references.

PS: This problem comes from physics. If a man has his own coordinate system on a point, how to know the corresponding coordinate system after his movement. I think it is a solved question, but I can't find related references.

Comment: I would say that in Riemannian geometry you rarely want to move a vector around. It's not as useful as it is in Euclidean geometry. But if you really want to move a vector from one point to another, what you often do is to connect the two points with a geodesic and, indeed, use the covariant derivative to parallel translate the vector from one point to another. I suggest looking up "parallel transport". Here's the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport#Parallel_transport_in_Riemannian_geometry

Comment: Yes, I know usually we only handle parallel transport, but if now a curve is given, and I just want to move a vector on the curve, how to realize it?

Comment: If the two points are $p_0,p_1 \in M$ and $c: [0,1] \rightarrow M$ is a smooth curve joining them (so $c(0) = p_0$ and $c(1) = p_1$), then, given $v \in T_{p_0}M$, the parallel transport of $v$ along $c$ is the solution to the system of ODEs given by $$ \nabla_{c'(t)}v(c(t)) = 0,$$ where $v(c(t)) \in T_{c(t)M$. $ Then $v(c(1)) \in T_{p_0}M$ is $v_0$ "moved" to $T_{p_1}M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a (piecewise) smooth curve $\alpha\colon [0,1] \to (M,g)$, and $v \in T_{\alpha(0)}M$ there is a unique solution to the initial value problem $$\frac{{\rm D}V}{{\rm d}t}(t) = 0, \quad V(0) = v$$defined on the interval $[0,1]$, since ${\rm D}V/{\rm d}t = 0$ is a first order linear ODE for the field $V$ along $\alpha$. Then $P\colon T_{\alpha(0)}M \to T_{\alpha(1)}M$ given by $P(v) = V(1)$ is what you want. In short, how to do the parallel translation of a vector along a curve? Take the unique parallel extension $V$ of the single vector $v$ to the curve $\alpha$, and look at the final value of this field $V$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I basically understand what you mean, but I don't know why it is a linear ODE. If I write out the covariant derivative, the affine connection seems complex. So are these first order PDEs? Must these PDEs have solutions? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: It's an ODE, not a PDE, everything there depends on the single variable $t$. It's linear because ${\rm D}/{\rm d}t$ is a linear operator on the space of fields along $\alpha$.

Comment: If you *really* must, the ODE is $\dot{V}^k +\Gamma_{ij}^k V^i \dot{x}^j=0$.

Comment: Okay. I understand. Thanks very much.